# Python checking if a variable is true without the == operator

Tags: python

I have recently stumbled upon this bit of code:

```py
def equal_button_press(self):  
    if self.add_trigger or self.sub_trigger or self.mult_trigger or self.div_trigger or self.asin_trigger:
```

In the `if` statement there is no specification for the code to check whether any of the variables `self.add_trigger`, `self.sub_trigger`, `self.mult_trigger`, `self.div_trigger` or `self.asin_trigger` are true.

Does this mean that it is possible to check if the object is true without the `==` operator?

Comment: `==` should *never* be involved in checking whether something is true.

Comment: See here,
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/

Comment: See also: [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Answer (score 3):

The `==` operator compares the value or equality of two objects, not if they are `True`. *If the 2 objects are equal, then python will return `True`*.

Here's a pretty great article going in depth about this: https://towardsdatascience.com/comparison-in-python-is-not-as-simple-as-you-may-think-a83eec69ab54

That being said, there are *truthy* and *falsy* values in Python:

> Values that evaluate to False are considered Falsy.
> Values that evaluate to True are considered Truthy.

Some *truthy* values include:

- Non-empty sequences or collections
- Numeric values that are not zero.

Some *falsy* values include:

- Zero of any numeric type.
- Empty sequences or collections
- `None` and `False`

So the code is checking which values are *truthy*, and those values will be outputted.

> With the Boolean OR operator, you can connect two Boolean expressions into one compound expression. At least one subexpressions must be true for the compound expression to be considered true, and it doesn’t matter which. If both subexpressions are false, then the expression is false.

Answer (score 0):

The clause inside of an `if` statement to determine whether it will be executed or not is not specifically only done when a value is equal to true *(In Python, `True`)* but can also be triggered if the variable or logical statement returns **any value** that is not 'falsy'.

@sj95126 provided the [exact answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) in the comments that I was also going to recommend on this!

Documentation Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to check if a value is `True` without the `==` operator.  An if statement takes a boolean after the `if` keyword.  The `==` operator checks if the 2 values on both sides are the same.  If they are, it "returns" `True`.  Otherwise, it "returns" `False`.

```
foo = True

# These if statments are the same
if foo == True:
    print("foo is True")

if foo:
    print("foo is True")
```